# Real Analysis: Sequence whose set of cluster points is another (strictly increasing) sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question I am working on is:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a fixed (and unspecified) strictly increasing sequence of real numbers. Find
>   (with proof) a sequence $(b_n)$ whose set of cluster points is precisely $(a_n)$.

However, I don't see how this could be true. For example, let $a_n := \sum_{i = 0}^n 10^{-i}$. Then $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing, and it's limit is $\frac{10}{9} = L$. Suppose $(b_n)$ were such a sequence where it's cluster points were exactly the points in $(a_n)$.

Then because $a_n \to L$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have some $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$, $d(a_n, L) < \varepsilon / 2$, and $d(b_i, a_n) < \varepsilon / 2$ for some $b_i$ (because $a_n$ is a cluster point of $(b_n)$), so $d(b_i, L) \leq d(b_i, a_n) + d(a_n, L) < \epsilon$. Picking such a $b_i$ for each $a_n$ gives a subsequence of $(b_n)$, $(b_{n_i})$, so that $b_{n_i} \to L$, so then $L$ is a limit point of $(b_n)$. Then $L$ must be a point in $a_i$. But there is no $n$ so that $\sum_{i = 0}^n 10^{-i} = \frac{10}{9}$.

So $(a_n)$ is a strictly increasing sequence of real numbers for which there can be no sequence whose cluster points are exactly $(a_n)$.

Comment: **HINT**: What got you in trouble was having the sequence $(a_n)$ converge in the first place!

Comment: @TedShifrin But the question doesn’t say the sequence can’t converge?

Comment: You're right. $(a_n)$ should "converge" to $+\infty$.

Comment: You argued that if $a_n\to L$, then $L$ will have to be a cluster point of $(b_n)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Which is true.

Comment: Your counterexample looks valid to me. There must be a missing hypothesis.

Comment: You are right. If the $set$ $S=\{a_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$  is  a subset of the set of cluster points of a sequence $B$, then any cluster point $L$ of the $sequence$ $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is also  a cluster point of $B$, and it may be that $L\not \in S.$

Answer (score 2):

You just need to design a sequence $(b_n)$ that gets arbitrarily close to every point in $(a_n)$. You have total freedom to choose the $b_n$'s. For example, the sequence $(b_n)$ could start out within $1$ of $a_1$; its next two terms could be within $\frac12$ of $a_1$ and $a_2$, the next three terms could be within $\frac13$ of $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, etc. Your job is to show that such a $(b_n)$ satisfies the requirements of your problem.

EDIT: As discussed in the comments, any construction of $b_n$ will also pick up $\lim a_n$ as a cluster point of $(b_n)$, unless the sequence $(a_n)$ is unbounded. When $(a_n)$ is bounded, the OP's argument shows how $\lim a_n$ will be a cluster point of $(b_n)$.

Comment: But wouldn’t this have the same problem I mentioned above, where such a sequence may have additional cluster points that are not elements of the sequence $(a_n)$?

Comment: This construction will ensure that the set of cluster points of $(b_n)$ includes every $a_n$, but this set may be a strict superset of $(a_n)$, e.g. if $(a_n)$ has cluster points not contained in $(a_n)$, as in the OP's example.

Comment: @Bungo  Quite right. It is hard to see how to avoid $L$ also being a limit point of any sequence $b_n$, unless the sequence $a_n$ is unbounded.

Comment: Even unboundedness wouldn't suffice in general. For example, $a_n$ could be something like $1, -1, 1/2, 2, -2, 1/3, 3, -3, 1/4, 4, -4, \ldots$ which is unbounded above and below but has zero as a cluster point that is not contained in the sequence, so $b_n$ will also cluster at zero. There's clearly a missing hypothesis, but I'm not sure what it should have been.

Comment: @Bungo We can still assume $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @grand_chat Ah right, sorry, forgot about that hypothesis. Strictly increasing and unbounded will suffice.